# Как реализовать поиск картинок в Node JS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, puppeteer

Разрабатываю сервис на Nest JS. В его базе данных содержится несколько тысяч компаний. Хочется на фронте показывать их логотип, но в Cloudinary их тоже нет. Я проверил, что логотипы легко гугляться в интернете и поэтому считаю логичным хранить их url-ы в БД. Но у меня не получается реализовать их поиск

```
const browser = await launch({
  headless: false,
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 1200 });
await page.goto(
  'https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+core&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS785US785&oq=.net+core&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i65j69i60.999j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8',
);

const IMAGE_SELECTOR = '#dimg_13';
const imageHref = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
  return document.querySelector(sel).getAttribute('src').replace('/', '');
}, IMAGE_SELECTOR);

const viewSource = await page.goto('https://www.google.com/' + imageHref);
fs.writeFile(
  '.googles-20th-birthday-us-5142672481189888-s.png',
  await viewSource.buffer(),
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('The file was saved!');
  },
);

browser.close();

console.log(imageHref);

return {
  url: `https://www.google.com/${imageHref}`,
};
```

Вот это моя текущая реализация. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Можете пояснить, что значит легко гуглятся, но не гугляся? Где именно в вашем коде возникают сложности и с чем?

Answer (score 0):

У меня никак не получалось написать селектор для поиска внутри Chrome. Но с Яндексом такой проблемы не было.

```
const browser = await launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
const query = `${companyName} логотип`;

await page.goto(`https://yandex.ru/images/search?from=tabbar&text=${query}`);

const link = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
  return document.querySelector(sel).getAttribute('src').replace('/', '');
}, 'div > a > img');

await browser.close();

return `https:/${link}`;
```

Держите кому надо)